# Taking the Top X results of a complex NHibernate query (QueryOver syntax)

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, queryover

I'm working with an Nhibernate Query where I have to do some complex queryover join aliases to eagerly load the children of my root entity. When loading, I want to filter the root entity results returned by a number of properties, including some which are on the children.

I've got this all working fine using joinaliases, but **where I'm stumped is filtering the results returned down to the top "X" instances of the root entity when ordered by a property other than the root entities Id**. Since I'm grabbing children, there are a number of duplicate rows returned by the SQL. If I try to filter the number of results with a .Take, the take executes before NHibernate collapses the result set down to the distinct root entities. For reference here's my domain model.

```
public class Project{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}
    public IList<ProjectRole> Team {get;set;}

}

public class ProjectRole{
   public User User {get;set;}
   public Role Role {get;set;}
}

public class User{
   public string LoginName {get;set;}
}
```

So I'm trying to grab all the projects where a User with the given LoginName is on the Project's Team. Then I want to order by the Project's value. I want to do this as efficiently as possible, without select n+1's etc.

**What does this community recommend?**

Additional Information:
As a stopgap, I'm currently returning all the results and then taking the top X in memory, but I don't want that to be permanent, because the query can return close to 10,0000 items, and I only want to top 7 or so. If I was writing straight SQL I'd just do something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Projects as p1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT distinct TOP (7)  
        topProjects.PGISourceItem_id as topsId, 
        topProjects.Value as topsValue
    FROM Projects topProjects            
        left outer join ProjectRoles roles on topProjects.Id=roles.Project_id 
        left outer join PGUsers users on roles.User_id=users.Id             
    WHERE 
        (users.LoginName like 'DEV\APPROVER' or this_0_1_.IsPrivate = 0)
    ORDER BY topProjects.Value desc
) as p2 on p1.Id = p2.topsId
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with NHibernate. The only subqueries I can create are either WHERE EXISTS or WHERE IN. And since I'm doing an ORDER BY Value I can't use WHERE IN because my select returns multiple properties.

Answer (score 0):

if users have under 1k projects this might work

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<User>()
    .Where(...)
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Projects, () => proj)
    .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(() => proj.Id)));

session.QueryOver<Foo>()
    .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(subquery)
    .Fetch(p => p.Collection)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
    .Take(5)
    .List();
```

Comment: I thought I tried something like that, and sql complains that Value by has to be part of the distinct projection. Basically since I don't select Value, it can't be part of the orderby statement.

Comment: Users actually might have more than 1K projects, so that's potentially not very performant. (Note they won't actually be on over 1K teams, but in reality my query also does an OR on the projects to select once they are not on but are publicaly visible.)

Comment: seems like your best bet is CreateSqlQuery();

Comment: Yeah at this point I'm planning to just do a two part query. First query grabs the top 7 as a projection consisting of Value,Id. Then in memory, convert that into a list of Ids to use in a second query that actually projects out all the data I need.